# Как спарсить изображения фильмов с сайта?

Tags: python, парсер

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import json


ua = UserAgent()



def collect_data(url):
    s = Service(executable_path=r"C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
    options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    main_page = driver.page_source


    soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page, 'lxml')

    all_items = []
    all_photos= []
    urls = []



    # print(find_img)
    # for i in find_img:
    #     img = find_img
    #     href = 'https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/' + img
    #
    #     all_photos.append({
    #         'photo':href
    #     })
    # with open('img.json','w') as f:
    #     json.dump(all_photos, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    # find_film = soup.find_all("h2", 'article-element')
    # for i in find_film:
    #     film_text = i.text.replace('\n','')
    #     # print(film_text)
    #
    #     all_items.append({
    #         'name':film_text
    #     }
    #     )
    #
    # with open("nw_films.json", "w") as file:
    #     json.dump(all_items, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False) # Сохраняем в json файл
    # return "[INFO] Everything is ok!"
def main():
    collect_data(url='https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Используя данный код, я спарсил названия фильмов, а картинки фильмов не могу, как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А этот вопрос не дубликат с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473848/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)? Или считать этот началом, а тот продолжением?

Ладно, не важно, здесь ещё речь про названия фильмов, потому дополню свой ответ.
Не надо использовать [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) там где в нём нет необходимости, [beautifulsoap](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoap) вполне достаточно для задачи.

```python
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

headings = soup.find_all('h2')
scripts = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')
data = json.loads(scripts[1].text)

films = {}
for idx in range(0,len(headings)):
    films[headings[idx].text.lstrip()] = data['image'][idx+1]['url']

for k,v in films.items():
    print('{}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(k,v))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
«Эта замечательная жизнь» (1946)
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/772/7726c28bfb402ee87314f50aeee9089e_cropped_666x447.jpg

«Эльф» (2003)
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/034/0340099af9679eee2998cdc71c6a5f7a_cropped_666x447.jpg

...

«Запомни ночь» (1940)
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/da8/da843b5e6df7ebb44d6b6a37c96322ca_cropped_666x447.jpg

«Магазинчик за углом» (1940)
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/4a0/4a017e83fed3728336e6d55a5df5273f_cropped_666x447.jpg
```

### Пояснение

1. `headings` — тут всё просто, не смотря на динамическую прогрузку страницы `html` разметка грузится полностью со всеми фильмами заранее.
   Если изучить страницу, то видно, что названия фильмов содержатся в теге `h2`, больше данный заголовок ни под что не используется, поэтому можно смело брать этот тег и ничего лишнего не выдумывать.
   Для заголовков в дальнейшем использую `.lstrip()`, т.к. в них содержатся балластные `\r\n`.
2. **Изображения** — конечно посложнее, но опять же динамическая загрузка заключается в том, что у нас заранее есть ссылки на изображения, потом *app_53bc76f060265b48b39e.js* подставляет их в теги `img`, но нам это заранее не видно. При этом ссылки на изображениям подтягиваются не через сетевые запросы, а значит они уже где-то есть 
   Долго искать не приходится, содержатся они в `json`е, который запрятан в теге `script`. Ищем такие `json`ы, он не единственный, поэтому берём второй `[1]`. Все ссылки на изображения содержатся в массиве в ключе `'image'`
3. Собираем `dict` из названий фильмов и изображений. Тут надо оговориться ⚠, что изображений будет на одной больлше, т.к. помимо фильмов там содержится первое изображение для статьи, которое ни к какому фильму не относится.
   Поэтому, проходимся по всем заголовкам и изображениям `+1`.

Comment: расскажите когда именно использовать selenium, а когда bs? Большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: как найти этот json файл? и как вообще искать нужные json файлы? P.s я знаю что это делается через консоль разработчика, но как искать именно нужные файлы с данными фильмов?

Comment: BS — это парсер, Selenium — пакет автоматизации браузеров **для проведения тестов**. На самом деле пользоваться надо тем что удобнее, но через Selenium парсить дико долго, поэтому этот вариант непредпочтителен на больших объёмах. Да и результаты не всегда предсказуемы. Как найти файл? Да везде разные условия будут, надо например по `DOM` поиcкать то что хочешь спарсить, можно чего-нибудь интересное найти типо этого JSON 

Comment: DiMIthras, большое спасибо, все еще не понятно как искать нужные json файлы, но попробую

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы спарсить изображения фильмов с сайта, вам нужно найти в исходном коде страницы теги , которые содержат в своем атрибуте src путь к изображению. Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Получаем исходный код страницы с помощью библиотеки requests
r = requests.get(url='https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/')

# Создаем объект BeautifulSoup из исходного кода страницы
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# Ищем все теги <img> на странице
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

# Перебираем все найденные теги <img> и выводим их атрибут src
for img_tag in img_tags:
    print(img_tag['src'])
```

В этом примере кода мы используем библиотеку requests для получения исходного кода страницы, а затем используем библиотеку BeautifulSoup для поиска всех тегов  на странице. После этого мы перебираем все найденные теги

Comment: Благодарю вас, позже попробую и обязательно вам все напишу