# Почему фотографии не парсятся?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Надо спарсить фотографии фильмов на сайте. Фотки грузятся динамически. Принял решение делать с помощью selenium и прокрутки страницы. Надо что бы прокручивалось до блока с реакциями, ведь далее идут не те фильмы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def get_photo(url):
s = Service(executable_path=r"C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(3)
    main_page = driver.page_source

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "reaction-comments-block")))
        except:
            print('Ошибка')  # Для отладки, после удалить
            continue

        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).perform()




        soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page, 'lxml')
        all_photos = soup.find_all('img')
        for i in all_photos:
            img = i.get('src')
            print(img)

        break
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
def main():
    get_photo(url='https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/')
```

Возвращается

```
    /_nuxt/logo-thevoice-full_b33872b.svg
/_nuxt/avatar_b1e8d42.png
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/af1/af164e36f5f8e02013d1443fe355e625_ce_2146x1429x94x149_cropped_666x444.jpg
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
/icon_thevoice.png
https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/25862525
```

Answer (score 1):

Не буду долго бухтеть на тему, что [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) используется для тестов, а не парсинга, хотя сам этим грешу

Но здесь не вижу особого смысла. Всё парсится силами одного только [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) и легко вытягивается из [json](/questions/tagged/json)

```python
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) '
                  'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'
}
url = 'https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')
data = json.loads(scripts[1].text)

for image in data['image']:
    print(image['url'])
```

###### Вывод:

```console
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/af1/af164e36f5f8e02013d1443fe355e625_ce_2146x1429x94x149.jpg
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/772/7726c28bfb402ee87314f50aeee9089e_cropped_666x447.jpg
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/034/0340099af9679eee2998cdc71c6a5f7a_cropped_666x447.jpg
...
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/4d4/4d4370f769900a727e14caaa02e641fe_cropped_666x446.jpg
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/da8/da843b5e6df7ebb44d6b6a37c96322ca_cropped_666x447.jpg
https://images.thevoicemag.ru/upload/img_cache/4a0/4a017e83fed3728336e6d55a5df5273f_cropped_666x447.jpg
```

Всего **65** изображений, последнее то, которое идёт перед реакцией.

```python
for image in data['image']:
    images.append(image['url'])
print(len(images))
>>> 65
```